# $\inf_{\Vert x\Vert}\Vert \lambda x-Tx\Vert=\frac{1}{\Vert R_T(\lambda)\Vert}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T\in L(E),\lambda\in\Bbb{K}.$ Denote $\alpha(\lambda)=\inf_{\Vert x\Vert}\Vert \lambda x-Tx\Vert.$

> I would like to prove that if $\lambda\in\Bbb{K}\setminus{\sigma(T)}$ that $$\alpha(\lambda)=\frac{1}{\Vert R_T(\lambda)\Vert}$$

Where $\sigma(T)$ denote the spectrum of $T$ and $R_T(\lambda)=(\lambda I-T)^{-1.}$

For this problem, not sure how can I start. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that $E$ is a Banach space and $T$ is a linear and bounded operator on $E$. I am right ?

Your problem is a spacial case of the following: if $A \in L(E)$ is invertible, then

$\frac{1}{||A^{-1}||}=\inf_{\Vert x\Vert=1}\Vert Ax\Vert.$

We have

$||A^{-1}||=\sup_{x \ne 0}\frac{||A^{-1}x||}{||x||}=\sup_{x \ne 0}\frac{||A^{-1}Ax||}{||Ax||}$.

The reason for the second $"="$: $A(E)=E$.

Hence $||A^{-1}||=\sup_{x \ne 0}\frac{||x||}{||Ax||}=\sup_{||x||=1}\frac{1}{||Ax||}$.

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't think to use only the definition... Thanks